# VBA pass a control reference in a dynamic menu

Tags: vba, excel

Im adding a right click cell menu per below but would like to pass the submenu's .Caption property to a handler; .OnAction someMacro(control .Caption) but it only seems to allow a string that references a macro; .OnAction "someMacro"

```
' Add a custom submenu with three buttons.
Set mySubMenu = ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, BEFORE:=1)
With mySubMenu
    .Caption = "Some Materials"
    .Tag = "Some_Cell_Control_Tag"
    For Each Item In substrateRng
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            ' using this onAction item causes recursive event to fire?
            '.OnAction = addSubstrate("kkkkk")
            .OnAction = "addSubstrate"
            '.FaceId = 95
            .Caption = Item.Value
        End With
    Next Item
End With
```

So I am looking for how to pass the chosen menu item's caption to a generic action otherwise it seems like i have to code each menu item's action to a unique macro?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pass arguments in the `OnAction` property. On the assumption that your argument is a `String` then you do it by enclosing the entire property in single quotes and each parameter in double quotes.

In your case the `Sub` might look a bit like this:

```
Public Sub addSubstrate(strValue as String)
    '...'
End Sub
```

And your calling line would be:

```
With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .Caption = Item.Value
    .OnAction = "'addSubstrate """ & .Caption & """'"
End With
```

I believe you can also pass Objects, so you could have a kind of `Sender` argument and pass the control itself so that you can access its `.Caption` property within the handling routine, but I've never done that myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Item In substrateRng
    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        ' using this onAction item causes recursive event to fire?
        '.OnAction = addSubstrate("kkkkk")
        .OnAction = "addSubstrate"
        '.FaceId = 95
        .Caption = Item.Value
        .parameter = .caption  'here you add the parameter value as desired 
    End With
Next Item
```

In your addsubstrate function, add the line to query the parameter:

```
dim paramInput as String
paramInput = Application.CommandBars.actionControl.parameter
' Or you could just use Application.CommandBars.actionControl.Caption
```